# Laravel increment id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 5 `foreach`s. So how do i increment i like

- 1
- 2
- 3

---

- 4
- 5
- 6

---

- 7
- 8
- 9

**View**

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
 {{ $i }}
@endforeach

@foreach($inquiries as $question)
 {{ $i }}
@endforeach

@foreach($queries as $question)
 {{ $i }}
@endforeach

@foreach($examinations as $question)
 {{ $i }}
@endforeach

@foreach($inquisitions as $question)
 {{ $i }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Put `$i = 0` above them and increment it within each iteration of foreach with `{{ ++$i }}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should try to below way.**

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
?>
@foreach($questions as $question)
 {{ $i++ }}
@endforeach

@foreach($inquiries as $question)
 {{ $i++ }}
@endforeach

@foreach($queries as $question)
 {{ $i++ }}
@endforeach

@foreach($examinations as $question)
 {{ $i++ }}
@endforeach

@foreach($inquisitions as $question)
 {{ $i++ }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Almost working sir. I just added `<?php $i = 0; ?>` top of foreach. and just put in `{{ $i++ }}` this one and it worked. Thank you sir. please fix little bit your code then i could accept an answer.

Comment: Sir can you explain why this $i++ this out of php tag? I think it will just print foreach times. I guess.

Comment: @RukaXing Unclear Please give me the brief description, So I can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use blade's variable dedicated to this:

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
    {{ $loop->iteration }}
@endforeach

@foreach($inquiries as $question)
    {{ $loop->iteration }}
@endforeach

@foreach($queries as $question)
    {{ $loop->iteration }}
@endforeach

@foreach($examinations as $question)
    {{ $loop->iteration }}
@endforeach

@foreach($inquisitions as $question)
    {{ $loop->iteration }}
@endforeach
```

[Blade docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#the-loop-variable).

Answer (score 1):

```
@php
  $i = 0;
@endphp
@foreach($questions as $question)
 {{ $i }}
  $i++;
@endforeach
```

use $i in each foreach loop as incremented $i++

Comment: Sir can you explain why this `$i++` this out of php tag? I think it will just print foreach times. I guess.

Answer (score 1):

if want your $i to change after every loop, you should be passing variable by reference.Check the article in the link below:
link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php